# group by query for latest record

Tags: php

I need group by query for only one table and using `group by` query display only latest record
I want to group by mobile number

My column names are as below :

`Reservation_id`,`Client_name`,`Email_address`,`Mobile_number`,`Vehical_type`

so i want to group by for this column and display latest record

I tried this query:

```
SELECT `Reservation_id`,`Client_name`,`Email_address`,`Mobile_number`
FROM `car_reservation` GROUP BY `Mobile_number` ASC       
ORDER BY `Reservation_id` ASC;
```

Comment: Hey guys, `GROUP BY ... ASC` ?

Comment: your question is not clear. can you you give us a example what should be output for given set of records?

Comment: see my answer below. ;)

Comment: `GROUP BY` doesn't work this way. It is not the tool you need to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is final QUERY `SELECT Reservation_id,Client_name,Email_address,Mobile_number,Pickup_date_time,Pickup_address,Drop_off_address,Distance,Total_price,Vehical_type
FROM car_reservation
WHERE Reservation_id IN (
    SELECT MAX(Reservation_id)
    FROM car_reservation
    GROUP BY Mobile_number
    ORDER BY Reservation_id desc
) ORDER BY Reservation_id DESC`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Reservation_id,Client_name,Email_address,Mobile_number FROM car_reservation WHERE Mobile_number in (SELECT Mobile_number FROM car_reservation ORDER BY Reservation_id ASC LIMIT 0,1);
```

I hope this is what you were expecting.

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
 $sql = "SELECT `Reservation_id`,`Client_name`,`Email_address`,`Mobile_number`
FROM car_reservation GROUP BY Mobile_number ASC ORDER BY Reservation_id ASC LIMIT 1";
```